# Modifying bike wiring harness to add hazard lights

Tags: automotive-engineering, electrical

I'm trying to modify my bike's harness.
Only trafficator functionality is supported by means of SPDT switch. I tried to add blinker functionality:

[image]

Kindly excuse the symbols for both Relay and Switch.
This should work all right, but I wanted the trafficator function to override the blinker function. I'm planning to add a switch for the DPDT Relay, which would be my blinker switch.
How should I go about it? A pure electrical solution would be nice with minimal component count and less connections. Thanks!

Comment: For a DC voltage system like this, use diodes to make solid override flashing?

Comment: Diodes are rugged, they are fine! Could you point me somewhere I could look?

Comment: Nvm you don't need them.  Can use open-close for flashing and close always overrides open.

Comment: Nope. How do I stop the other indicator from blinking, when my hazards were on, and I tried to signal any one direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, it's still impractical, and involves lots of components:
[image]

Sorry, couldn't post in the morning: got the flu, didn't expect downvote.
PS: After attempt at solution:
[image]

Comment: You have a few problems there. (1) There seems to be a link missing between the L and R switches. The L switch has no feed. (2) If the flasher is always on then the relay will be continuously switching. (3) When the relay switches on its twin contacts will switch over to the diodes but the third contact will open the NC contact and disconnect the supply. The diodes will never conduct any current so diodes and relay are doing nothing for you. Back to the drawing board, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yup, I noticed the thing about the cutoff relay, it's not being triggered correctly. Please ignore the symbol for both the spdt switch and the dpdt relay. Any recommendations for drawing quick schematics? I don't want to go to kicad just for small circuit.

Comment: Your new circuit has no way to switch on hazard mode. It still suffers error (3) from my previous comment.

Comment: That's the magic: it will not open, because if the indicator switch is default off, the first diode will not allow backwards current!

Comment: I'm not sure which of my sentences your comment is addressing but your new circuit has no hazard switch. There is no way to get both left and right to flash together. If the turn switch is in the off position no current can flow anywhere. Every branch will be open-circuit.

Comment: Didn't I mention earlier that I was having difficulties drawing the schematics, as I'm a new guy, also might have missed switch types also. The switch triggering the electromagnet for the dpdt switch ( I mentioned relay below) would be the hazard switch. The indicator switch is of on-off-on type, so it doesn't need to be L or R always. If only someone might have helped me with a good schematic editor, that would have been much nicer: instead I get downvoted.

Comment: [free+online+electrical+schematic+drawing](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+online+electrical+schematic+drawing&rlz=1C1ZKTG_enIE827IE827&oq=free+online+electrical+schematic+drawing).

Comment: OK. If 'DPDT Relay' is actually a switch rather than a relay then your circuit should work. Since the NC contacts aren't connected you could use a DPST switch instead.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try just bridging out the two sets of lamps with a switch. To switch on hazard mode close the switch and select either left or right indicator.

How this works out depends on whether or not your flasher will operate correctly with double the load. (Disclaimer: I never owned a motor bike.)

---

The single switch option:

[image]

---

The indicator-hazard override option:

The logic required is:

- Left lamp = SW<sub>L</sub> OR (NOT SW<sub>R</sub> AND SW<sub>H</sub>)
- Right lamp = SW<sub>R</sub> OR (NOT SW<sub>L</sub> AND SW<sub>H</sub>)

[image]

If either turn indicator is switched on its associated relay will energise in sync with the flasher. The NC contact will disconnect the hazard feed to the other indicator lamp.

2 × relays. 4 × diodes.

D3 and D4 may be omitted but you may see a very short pulse while the relays energise.

Comment: I thought about this circuit, and added the relay, so that I don't have to close the indicator switch for the hazard lights to glow.

Comment: That will usually blow a 2 way flasher unit - test and see.

Comment: It's fine!:) My bike's trafficator light is only 10W each, and the flasher could take like 4-5A easily.

Comment: @user2338150, see the update.

Comment: Still doesn't meet the override requirement. I'm almost near a solution, shall try to post in the morning! Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Are you saying that selecting left or right indicator while the hazard function is on should suppress the hazard function? That's not clear from your original post.

Comment: Yes, what else is there to override?:)

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a unit capable of 2 and 4 way flashers and then all that is needed is an extra switch.

Done that conversion on several old cars.

Comment: Aren't they mechanically decoupled? I mean, say if my SPDT switch could mechanically decouple the hazard switch, I wouldn't need much. I'll try to look more on these relays though.

Comment: So, a lot depends on the original circuit and how you change it to match. Even changing a single indicator warning light for two - those in the dash…